# When does a site send back 200 OK to referrer?

Tags: php, http, redirect, httpresponse

I'm trying to understand a concept of HTTP response codes but having some confusion.

I have a site that takes payments from a payment gateway. The customer is redirected to the gateway site and then after payment the gateway redirects back to my site's callback function.

This all works fine, however, the problem is that my site's callback function takes the response code and redirects it to a success or fail page.

The payment gateway gets passed back the the "302" redirect header occurring from this and considers that a security risk, even though it is an internal redirect with no data being passed over (since 302 doesn't keep POST/GET vars anyway). So it cancels the payment.

But really, when the gateway hits my callback function, shouldn't that send back a 200 since it was found and I would think that would be sent back to the gateway and satisfy them. From that point on, whatever happens internally should be none of their concern or knowledge. But it seems 200 doesn't get sent until the final landing page is reached and page execution stops.

The only work around I found to "fool" the gateway is to use a javascript redirect or meta redirect as it doesn't pass back the redirect header code. But is there a better way or something I should be doing differently?

Comment: "redirects back to my site's callback function" makes absolutely no sense.  Can you describe better what is happening here?  Are they POST-ing data separately than the client session?  Or does that data come back to your script client-side?  Tell us what is going on, and maybe we can be of better help.

Comment: Who is hitting the callback function? The payment processor, or is the payment processor redirecting the user to the callback page?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: Do not redirect the payment gateways return path.  You need to handle your success/fail logic differently and transparently to the payment processor.

Comment: @DssTrainer You seem intent on using a redirect of some sort, I'm saying you do not have to and that would be better.  You asked if there was a better way or something you should do differently...  Problem solved.

Comment: But that isn't really an option. Shopping carts do redirects all the time. You get a pass/fail message from the gateway and you have to finalize the order and show the customer a success page. This can be done differently if the gateway supports a "notify url" and a "success url" in which you can pass the customer back to the success url directly and pass the result code back to the notify url and leave both pages to stop there. But this gateway doesn't have 2 url options. So I need to do both from the one url it sends back to.

Comment: @DssTrainer What shopping cart? You don't need two URLs you can manage the success and notify logic on ONE page.  You're using PHP, this is trivial stuff...  Or you can do your js/meta redirect hack, there aren't any other solutions.

Comment: ok then JS/meta is the only solution. There's no way to hide or fake the response back to the gateway?